# How can I get a modified copy of a immutable object?

Tags: python-3.x, immutability, copy-constructor, python-3.8, python-attrs

How can I get a modified copy of a immutable object?

I.e. how could `some_magical_method` look like in this snipped?

```py
import attr

@attr.s(frozen=True, slots=True)
class Config:
    param1: int = attr.ib()
    param2: str = attr.ib()

my_base_config = Config(param1=1, param2="2")
my_derived_config = my_base_config.some_magical_method(param2="two")

print(my_derived_config.param1) # output: 1
print(my_derived_config.param2) # output: two
```

Background: I want to use immutable objects for my configuration. But I also want to avoid code duplication when dealing with very similar configurations, e.g. for unit tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attrs` has a function specifically for you: https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.evolve

Since it takes the instance as a first arguments you can use it to define a method too:

```py
@attr.s
class C:
    some_magical_method = attr.evolve
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that does what you want! Add it to your object, here's my code and output:

```
@attr.s(frozen=True, slots=True)
class Config:
    param1: int = attr.ib()
    param2: str = attr.ib()

    def some_magical_method(self, **kwargs):
        params_to_use = {"param1": self.param1, "param2": self.param2}
        params_to_use.update(kwargs)
        new_obj = Config(**params_to_use)
        return new_obj

my_base_config = Config(param1=1, param2="2")
my_derived_config = my_base_config.some_magical_method(param2="two")

>>> print(my_derived_config.param1) # output: 1
1
>>>print(my_derived_config.param2) # output: two
two
```

The key here is that the method creates the new Config object,  using its own values first, and then overwriting with any that are passed into the method using `params_to_use.update(kwargs)`. The updated values are then passed to the constructor/init of the new object, which is returned.

Hope that helps, Happy Coding!